# Update duplicate table in network location from local copy

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to create an Update Query in Access 2010 to update a duplicate table on our shared drive from the user's local copy.

The Access program itself uses the usual split front end / back end.

Due to frequent drops over VPN, we came up with a method for:

- downloading the latest version of the front end and a copy of the back end to the user's local drive
- then running off of the local front end / back end (with the two linked)
- and then using VBA to update individual records on both the local and network locations, unless the network drive is unavailable, where it then dumps the updated data into an array to be attempted again at program close.

I have two identical tables (one on the local and one on the network) that I need to create an Update Query to update any changes made in the local table to the one on the network so that it can be stored on the network database for the next user on their machine.

```
UPDATE HiringMgrData As NetworkHiringMgrData IN '\\ServerName\FilePath\HREmails_be.accdb'
SET NetworkHiringMgrData.UserName  = HiringMgrData.UserName, 
   NetworkHiringMgrData.UserPhone = HiringMgrData.UserPhone, 
   NetworkHiringMgrData.UserEmail = HiringMgrData.UserEmail  
WHERE NetworkHiringMgrData.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM HiringMgrData)
```

This gives me an error when it gets to the SET statements, and clicking through simply blanks the fields in the network table.

I'm trying to "trick" Access into treating the table in the network database as NetworkHiringMgrData, while keeping the name of table in the the local database HiringMgrData, in hopes that Access will be able to distinguish between the two.

In reality, both the local and network databases have a table named HiringMgrData with field names of ID, UserName, UserPhone, and UserEmail.

I was able to get the Append Query to work using:

```
INSERT INTO HiringMgrData IN '\\ServerName\FilePath\HREmails_be.accdb'
SELECT HiringMgrData.*
FROM HiringMgrData;
```

which simply adds any new records from the HiringMgrData table in the local database to the HiringMgrData table in the network database, but I cannot update the existing records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below.  I was attempting to do something similar on my MS Access Database and for some reason this worked for me instead of using IN 'network path'

`UPDATE [\\ServerName\FilePath\HREmails_be.accdb].HiringMgrData As NetworkHiringMgrData 
inner join HiringMgrData as LocalHiringMgrData on NetworkHiringMgrData.ID = LocalHiringMgrData.ID
SET NetworkHiringMgrData.UserName  = LocalHiringMgrData.UserName, 
   NetworkHiringMgrData.UserPhone = LocalHiringMgrData.UserPhone, 
   NetworkHiringMgrData.UserEmail = LocalHiringMgrData.UserEmail;`

Answer (score 0):

I think your `WHERE` clause is wrong and should be

```
WHERE NetworkHiringMgrData.ID = HiringMgrData.ID;
```

---

Note that this may generate lots of network traffic as all records are updated. Maybe your application can manage an `isChanged` flag and update only those records.

Comment: I tried this an it is still giving me an error, asking for the parameter value of HiringMgrData.UserName, HiringMgrData.UserPhone, and HiringMgrData.UserEmail.

I'll look into the isChanged flag, thanks for the suggestion!